# Integrate Whatsapp URL Scheme into an app

Tags: hyperlink, uri, href, url-scheme, whatsapp

Hello Folks at Stack Overflow from all over the world! Hope you're all doing pretty well! I have a quick question to ask. Has any of you found out or knows about a workaround to get a Whatsapp URL scheme to open a screen to draft a custom message and specifying a custom contact as well. I have already read the documentation on the Whatsapp website using the abid (Address Book ID) or text parameter but this does not lead me anywhere. if we want to send a custom email for instance we simply use:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=custom subject;body=custom message">E-mail</a>
```

Is there such a workaround with Whatsapp Messeger?

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated folks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cant provide a solution for this problem, but I think, https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013 as it describe the Whatsapp API.